# Reassigning strings to a set list of values in an array

Tags: arrays, string, lua, substitution

I have a list in Lua which is fixed format (it's an input from somewhere else).

E.g.

```
a = {"apple", "apple 1", "pear", "orange", "orange 3", "kiwi", "tomato"}
```

I also have a look up table where I want to normalise this set and send them to a code format. Note: anything containing apple, such as apple 1, apple 2 etc will be mapped to the same value as apple.

E.g.

```
"apple" => "RD"
"pear" => "GR"
"orange" => "OG"
"kiwi" => "GR"
"tomato" => "RD"
"banana" => "YL"
etc...
```

I then want to return a list with all of these substitutions:

```
fruitBox = {"RD", "GR", "OG"}
```

I don't mind if `fruitBox` has repeated values or not, whatever is easiest, but it should only return values if they are represented in both the lookup and the original list. I have been trying to do this but matching the strings, but I always end up getting stuck with how to output the codes. I also tried `string.gsub` and iterating through a `for loop` but still got nowhere useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to store the list of mappings in a (hash) table and iterate over the first list changing the elements using the mapping from the second table. Something like this should work:

```
local a = {"apple", "pear", "orange", "kiwi", "tomato"}
local map = {
  apple = "RD",
  pear = "GR",
  orange = "OG",
  kiwi = "GR",
  tomato = "RD",
  banana = "YL",
}
for index = 1, #a do
  a[index] = map[a[index]] or "missing mapping"
end

-- print results
for index = 1, #a do print(a[index]) end
```

This prints `RD GR OG GR RD` for me.

If you *really* want to skip the elements not present in the mapping (which I don't recommend, as it will be difficult to find errors in the mapping or the data), then use a separate table and do `table.insert` instead of `a[index]...` assignment in the loop.

If the strings have some non-letters (as in the updated question), you may want to remove them using `gsub("%A","")` or something similar.

Comment: This is great thank - you! However, it doesn't work if the strings have numbers in them, which is crucial to my problem. Have edited the question to add this in.

Comment: Added in: `for i = 1, #a do
  a[i] = a[i]:gsub("%A","")
end` which works fine. If you have a neater solution feel free to add into your answer :)

Comment: @Bee, it's a valid comment, but it's not related to the question and will only complicate the answer, so let's leave it as is.

Comment: As I mentioned, I did amend the answer as it is pretty crucial to what I was trying to do. You my other amend to your answer was to actually return it as a table, as the original question specified. In any case, thank you for your help.