# How to remove repeated string values from a list

Tags: lua

This is a continuation of a previous [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57060993/reassigning-strings-to-a-set-list-of-values-in-an-array-in-lua).

I have a fixed list in Lua which I am reassigning values for

```lua
local a = {"apple", "pear", "orange", "kiwi", "tomato"}
local map = {
  apple = "RD",
  pear = "GR",
  orange = "OG",
  kiwi = "GR",
  tomato = "RD",
  banana = "YL",
}
colours = {}
for index = 1, #a do
  table.insert(colours,map[a[index]or "OT")
end
```

Now I would either like to edit the existing script, or add some new script, to remove any repeated values.

My end result should be a table (colours) with no repeated values or empty strings, but I can't seem to think of a neat way to do this!

If it's not possible (or really messy) my second option would be to count the number unique values in the table.

Comment: do you just need a list of colors or does their order matter?

Comment: @Piglet order doesn't matter

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to run over the entire table every time you add an element you can simply create a second table where you remember which colours have been listed yet.
Simply use the colour as key.

```
local a = {"apple", "pear", "orange", "kiwi", "tomato"}
local map = {
  apple = "RD",
  pear = "GR",
  orange = "OG",
  kiwi = "GR",
  tomato = "RD",
  banana = "YL",
}

local listedColours = {}
local colours = {}
for _,colour in pairs(a) do
  colour = map[colour] or "OT"
  if not listedColours[colour] then
    table.insert(colours, colour)
    listedColors[colour] = true
  end      
end
```

Comment: just a spelling error in here which stops it running! (I think it's left over from the fact I'm British and spelt colour as such). Lovely concise answer

Comment: @Bee I'm German, please discuss those spelling issues with the Americans ;)
I'll use whatever you manage to agree on.

Comment: They will never agree on BrE with all it's extra letters! Thanks for correcting it to the right way though ;)

Answer (score 3):

Solution i suggest: add to `table` function `contains`

```
table.contains = function(t, value)
    for index = 1, #t do
        if t[index] == value then
            return index    
        end
    end
end
```

so problem with having only unique colours can be solved like:

```
for index = 1, #a do
    local colour = map[a[index]] or "OT"
    if not table.contains(colours, colour) then
        table.insert(colours, colour)
    end
end
```

I consider it pretty neat

Comment: I like this solution and it does work. I'll leave the question open a bit longer in case someone comes up with a shorter solution (as per the SE guidelines)

Comment: Oh just one thing though, you're missing a `]` line 2 of the second script box